# parameter equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have question about solving equation depending on the parameter $m$

$|x+1|+x=\frac{4m-3}{m+1}$

of course first I determine the numerical range for the absolute value and I have two cases

first instance

when $x<-1$

$-1=\frac{4m-3}{m+1}$ so $m=\frac{2}{5}$

second instance

$x\ge-1$

$2x+1=\frac{4m-3}{m+1}$

$x=\frac{3m-4}{2m+2}$

$\frac{3m-4}{2m+2}\ge-1$

$m\ge \frac{2}{5} \vee m<-1$

so the answer is $m\ge \frac{2}{5}$ and $m<-1$ is it correct?

Comment: I'm assuming the task is to find all $m$ for which there exists a solution $x$. In that case your answer is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, indeed, your answer is correct, $$m \lt -1 \;\text{or}\; m\geq \frac 25, \;\text{ alternatively, } \; m \in (-\infty, -1) \cup \left[\frac 25, +\infty\right)$$ which defines the range of values $m$ for which a solution in $x$ exists.